# How to remove key in nested dictionary?

Tags: python

I got this obj:

```
{
    '2022-09-08T15:00:00Z': {
        'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M':{
            "DVENTO": [
                {'value' : '95.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag': 'GOOD','structure' : 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M', 'element' : 'DVENTO'}],
            "TD_MN_C":[
                {'value' : '6.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag': 'GOOD','structure' : 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M', 'element' : 'TD_MN_C'},]
            },
    },
```

but i want to delete key 'INMET_BRASILIA_A0001' and do somethins like this

```
{
    '2022-10-11T14:00:00Z': {
                'PRESS_HPA': [{'value': '915.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag': 'GOOD', 'structure': 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M', 'element': 'PRESS_HPA'}],

                'PRESS_MX_HPA': [{'value': '82', 'quality': 'qf-UNCHECKED', 'quality_flag': 'UNCHECKED', 'structure': 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M', 'element': 'PRESS_MX_HPA'}]

                }
```

Comment: From where `PRESS_HPA` keyword comes from?

Comment: Your desired result would be more useful if it actually included data from your example dict.

Comment: There is no `INMET_BRASILIA_A0001` in your dictionary. Did you mean `INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M`?

Answer (score 0):

Set the top-level dictionary element to the nested element to remove a level of nesting.

```
obj['2022-09-08T15:00:00Z'] = obj['2022-09-08T15:00:00Z']['INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a key, you can do something like this:

```
d1 = { 
        'a': { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 },
        'b': { 'x': 4, 'y': 5 },
    }

print(d1)

key1, key2 = 'a', 'y'
removed_value = (d2 := d1.get(key1)) and d2.pop(key2, None)

print(removed_value)
print(d1)
```

returns:

```
{'a': {'x': 1, 'y': 2}, 'b': {'x': 4, 'y': 5}}
2
{'a': {'x': 1}, 'b': {'x': 4, 'y': 5}}
```

where:

```
(d2 := d1.get(key1))
```

will look up the nested dictionary into d2; if the key is not present `get` will return `None` and the remainder of the `and` will not be evaluated; similarly if the second lookup fails `removed_value` will be set to `None`, otherwise the value being removed will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can pop the key and assign it to the original dictionary.

```
keys_to_remove = ['INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M']
for k, v in d.items():
    for key in keys_to_remove:
        d[k] = v.pop(key)
```

Result:

```
{'2022-09-08T15:00:00Z': {'DVENTO': [{'value': '95.0',
    'quality': 'qf-GOOD',
    'quality_flag': 'GOOD',
    'structure': 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M',
    'element': 'DVENTO'}],
  'TD_MN_C': [{'value': '6.0',
    'quality': 'qf-GOOD',
    'quality_flag': 'GOOD',
    'structure': 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M',
    'element': 'TD_MN_C'}]}}
```